# Integrating Stripe Checkout JS with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, stripe-payments

I am trying to use the standard stripe checkout javascript code, embedded on my page:

```
<form action="/charge" method="POST">
  <script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh"
data-image="/square-image.png"
data-name="Demo Site"
data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
data-amount="2000">
  </script> 
</form>
```

I'm also using the custom CSS located here:

http://html5up.net/helios

When the user clicks on the checkout button, the overlay doesn't pop up - does anyone know if there's some way to somehow escape the stripe checkout?